# What to use instead of subset to get a vector result in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, vector, subset

My question is a relatively simple problem that I would usually solve with `subset`.  In this case I need a vector rather than a data frame as the result and I'm hoping someone can help.

I have a data frame with two columns, species and ID.

```
Species     ID
Species1    A01
Species1    A02
Species1    B01
Species1    B02
Species2    A03
Species2    A04
Species2    B03
Species2    B04
Species3    A05
Species3    A06
Species3    B05
Species3    B06
Species3    B07
```

For each species I would like to create a vector of the associated ID's for that species.

Using subset I would do:

```
df2 <- subset(df1, Species == Species1, select = "ID")
```

and the result would be

```
ID
A01
A02
B01
B02
```

But this gives me the result as a data frame and I'd like the result as a vector.

I've looked for an answer and not been able to find one, and given I'm fairly new to R - perhaps if there is a knowledge gap, this could be explained.

Comment: `unlist(subset(...))` or `df1$ID[df1$Species=="Species1"]` or `with(df1, ID[Species=="Species1"]` or ...

Comment: Thanks @Cath the first gives a strange result - naming each value in the vector with the ID_1, ID_2 etc but the second works perfectly.

Comment: If you just insert `as.vector()` function? `df2 <- as.vector(subset(df1, Species == Species1, select = "ID"))`

Comment: I thought this would work too, but it doesn't in this case.  It still returns a result in a single column with numbered rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the argument `drop = TRUE` in `subset` to return a vector.

```
subset(df1, Species == "Species1", select = ID, drop = TRUE)
# [1] A01 A02 B01 B02
```

Comment: Perfect.  This is the simple solution I was looking for.  Thank-you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a minimal example of your data.frame as I understand it:

```
cat <- c("A01", "A02", "B01", "B02", "A03")
species <- c("species1", "species1", "species1", "species2", "species2")
x_name <- "species"
y_name <- "ID"
df <- data.frame(species, cat)
names(df) <- c(x_name, y_name)
df
species  ID
1 species1 A01
2 species1 A02
3 species1 B01
4 species2 B02
5 species2 A03
```

What I'd do is subset as you said, then assign a new variable, specify the data type, and unlist as Cath suggested above using brackets to specify the column:

```
df2 <- subset(df, species == "species1")
df2
species  ID
1 species1 A01
2 species1 A02
3 species1 B01

a <- as.character(unlist(df2[,2], use.names = F))
a
[1] "A01" "A02" "B01"
is.vector(a)
[1] TRUE

df3 <- subset(df, species == "species2")   
df3
species  ID
4 species2 B02
5 species2 A03 

b <- as.character(unlist(df3[,2], use.names = F))
b
[1] "B02" "A03"
is.vector(b)
[1] TRUE
```